# How do I connect to a database on a different server, say db4free.net from a pdo codeigniter project hosted on heroku

Tags: codeigniter, heroku

I am trying to host a codeigniter project on heroku, using an external mysql database at db4free.net.

I have tried all I can to no avail but my last effort looks like this

```html
$db['mysql'] = array(
 'dsn' => 'mysql:hostname="db4free.net"; dbname=ravenstock',
 'hostname' => '',
 'username' => 'ravenstockadmin',
 'password' => '**************',
 'database' => '',
 'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
 'dbprefix' => '',
 'pconnect' => FALSE,
 'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
 'cache_on' => FALSE,
 'cachedir' => '',
 'char_set' => 'utf8',
 'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
 'swap_pre' => '',
 'encrypt' => FALSE,
 'compress' => FALSE,
 'stricton' => FALSE,
 'failover' => array(),
 'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Please Try This...**

```
'hostname' => '45.113.122.253:3306',
'username' => 'your server username',
'password' => 'your server password',
'database' => 'server database name',
'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
```